# Django - signals. Simple examples to start

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I am new to Django and I'm not able to understand how to work with Django signals. Can anyone please explain "**Django signals**" with simple examples?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific? The manual has a few examples already: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signals/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/ is the working link

Answer (score 44):

You can find very good content about django signals over Internet by doing very small research.

Here i will explain you very brief about Django signals.
**What are Django signals?**
Signals allow certain senders to notify a set of receivers that some action has taken place

Actions :

**model's save() method is called.**
django.db.models.signals.pre_save | post_save

**model's delete() method is called.**
django.db.models.signals.pre_delete | post_delete

**ManyToManyField on a model is changed.**
django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed

**Django starts or finishes an HTTP request.**
django.core.signals.request_started | request_finished

All signals are django.dispatch.Signal instances.

## very basic example :

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import signals

def create_customer(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print "Save is called"

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=32)

signals.post_save.connect(receiver=create_customer, sender=Customer)
```

**Shell**

```
In [1]: obj = Customer(name='foo', description='foo in detail')

In [2]: obj.save()
Save is called
```

Comment: A question - Why is `signals.post_save.connect(receiver=create_customer, sender=Customer)` called after the definition of `Customer` model? Also, why isn't that line indented? Won't that line execute even if class definition is not called? i.e if `models.py` is imported anywhere but no objects (class definitions, functions, etc.) from `models.py` are actually invoked.

Comment: Feels incomplete this answer.

Answer (score 20):

Apart from the [explanation given by Prashant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27805609/320399), you can also use **receiver** decorator present in `django.dispatch` module.

e.g.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=32)

@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=Customer)
def create_customer(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print "customer created"
```

For more information, refer to this [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html).

Comment: In Prashant answer, used from `signals.post_save` and in your answer used from `signals.pre_save`, what's the difference between these?

Comment: These two are two different signals, which gets emitted at different stages, during model persistence in db. post_save is after saving the model, pre_save is before saving the model.

Comment: `post_save` usage is clear but what's usage of `pre_save`?

Comment: This signal is triggered before saving the model..You can think of it as an interceptor, where you can execute something, before saving the model.

Comment: is this means that in this situation call_back function always calls except at saving moment? or this means is when you are trying writing a filed in Django model before saving call_back function calls?

Comment: but your example is not correct with pre_save, because it says "customer created"

Answer (score 0):

In the signals.post_save.connect(receiver=create_customer, sender=Customer)... sender will always be the model which we are defining... or we can use the User as well in the sender.

Answer (score 0):

Signals are used to perform any action on modification of a model instance. The signals are utilities that help us to connect events with actions. We can develop a function that will run when a signal calls it. In other words, Signals are used to perform some action on modification/creation of a particular entry in Database. For example, One would want to create a profile instance, as soon as a new user instance is created in Database

There are 3 types of signal.

1. pre_save/post_save: This signal  works before/after the method save().
2. pre_delete/post_delete: This signal  works before after delete a model’s instance (method delete()) this signal is thrown.
3. pre_init/post_init: This signal is thrown before/after instantiating a model (**init**() method).

One of the example, if we want to create a profile of a user as soon as the user is created using post_save signal.

For code example, I found the Geeks for Geeks, which explains is very simple way, and easy to understand.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-and-use-signals-in-django/

Answer (score 0):

You can add signals to your *models.py* file

here is an example for adding an auto slug, if you use a `SlugField`:

**this is the stuff you need to import**

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
```

---

**Add the @receiver to the bottom of your class, included the def**

> If you add the `def __str__(self):` under the receiver, you will get an error

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Store)
def store_pre_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = slugify(instance.name)
```

**or you can use post_save**

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

@receiver(post_save, sender=Store)
def store_post_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = slugify(instance.name)
        instance.save()
```

I found this example from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEX50LJrFuU)